# What is the application/process that enables us to see the desktop on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I am trying to figure out what is the name of application that shows us the desktop?
It's not the Finder, not a system ui server, then what is it?

I want to know the positions of various windows of application on window server. I have CGContext for them with me. Is it possible to get that information from WindowServer?

Can we use Accessibility API for this or any other technique?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window management system is known as Quartz Compositor. The actual process shows up as "WindowServer" in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score -1):

That's VNC server. However, this is actually not the programming question.